Dependence on Urysohn's lemma in Cartan's construction of Haar measure
This question was posted by someone else on stackexchange three months ago, but no one has answered as of yet:

Cartan's 1940 paper, Sur la mesure de Haar, claims to provide a proof of the existence and uniqueness of Haar measure for locally compact abelian groups without the use of axiom of choice. However, Cartan claimed the existence of a partition of unity, citing Dieudonné's paper which ultimately uses Urysohn's lemma.


Similarly, in Alfsen's exposition of a simplified version of Cartan's argument, Alfsen also claimed the existence of a partition of unity without elaboration.


Given that Urysohn's lemma is not provable without choice, my questions are

can we construct partitions of unity on locally compact spaces without invoking Urysohn's lemma or any form of choice?
Do we truly have a choice-free proof of the existence and uniqueness of Haar measure for locally compact abelian groups?


Thank you for sharing your expertise:)

It likely depends on the form in which the group is described. Haar measure is not unique; it depends on the choice of the compact neighbourhood of unity that will have measure 1. To get around that, we can assume that such a neighbourhood (or a compactly supported continuous function) is given with the group, or just assume that the group is compact.

@user95282 doesn’t choice of the neighborhood of unity only scale the Haar measure by a constant? Please correct me if my understanding is flawed. That aside, the proof establishes existence and (essential) uniqueness for any locally compact group, so I am not clear why one should assume the group is compact.

My guess: Cartan was not (yet) aware of the use of AC in proving Urysohn's Lemma (the principle DC was formulated later and that Urysohn's Lemma implies a bit of choice was proved even later.

One more thought: you can cheat and avoid Urysohn's Lemma in Cartan's proof of his approximation theorem by taking a pseudometric $d$ on the group such that $B(e,1)\subseteq U$ and use it to create the Urysohn functions in the familiar way.
To get the pseudometric take a sequence $\langle V_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ of symmetric  neighbourhoods of $e$ such that $V_{n+1}^3\subseteq V_n$ for all $n$ and $V_0\subseteq U$; apply the proof of Kakutani's theorem that first-countable groups are metrizable to the sequence to get the pseudometric and $V_{n+1}\subseteq B(e,2^{-n})\subseteq V_n$ and ... .

... there you are. The construction of the pseudometric is completely constructive. The cheating bit: you use Dependent Choice to create the sequence $\langle V_n:n\in\omega\rangle$. All you know is that for every neighbourhood $U$ of $e$ there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $e$ such that $V^3\subseteq U$ and you can't get the sequence without appeal to a higher authority; in this case DC is a high enough authority.

@DJForklift Yes, the Haar measure is unique up to a constant. But you have to choose that constant (or a compact neighbourhood that should have measure 1). My suggestion to assume that the group is compact was meant to simplify the question --- maybe AC is needed even for compact groups. But it all depends on how the group is presented.

A partial answer.
Inspection of Dieudonné's proof shows three things.

it only uses complete regularity of the compact space $X$: it begins,
given a finite open cover $\mathcal{O}$ of the space, by taking for every
point $x$ an $O_x\in\mathcal{O}$ with $x\in O_x$ and then a continuous
function $f_x:X\to[0,1]$ with $f_x(x)=1$ and $f_x(y)=0$ if $y\notin O_x$.
By compactness there is a finite set $F$ such that for every $y$ there is
an $x\in F$ with $f_x(y)>0$.
The partition of unity is formed as always: set $f=\sum_{x\in F}f_x$ and then
let $h_x=f_x/f$.

it uses the Axiom of Choice when taking for each $x$ an open set $O_x$ and
a continuous function $f_x$.

it yields a partition of unity on the whole space.


Consequences of these:

one can avoid the use of Urysohn's Lemma by showing first that every
topological group is completely regular.
This can be done by noting that every topological group is uniformizable:
if $V$ is a neighbourhood of $e$ then one can form the cover
$\mathcal{U}_V=\{xV:x\in G\}$ or the entourage $U_V=\{(x,y):x^{-1}y\in V\}$
of the diagonal.
The family of all such covers $\mathcal{U}_V$ is a base for a covering
uniformity and the entourages $U_V$ form a base for the equivalent `entourage'
uniformity.
Theorem 8.1.10 in Engelking's book yields sufficiently many continuous
pseudometrics on $G$ that in turn yield enough continuous functions to show
that $G$ is completely regular.

this appears to imply that Cartan's proof uses the Axiom of Choice after
all, albeit in the background.
One can avoid this particular instance by looking at the family $F$ of
all non-negative and continuous functions $f$ for which there is
an $O\in\mathcal{O}$ such that $f(x)>0$ for some $x\in O$ and $f(y)=0$
whevener $y\notin O$. Taking a finite subfamily $G$ of $F$ such that
$\bigcup_{g\in G}\{x:g(x)>0\}=X$ works just as well.

if one applies Dieudonné's proof in Cartan's case then one obtains a finite
set $\{h_i:i\le n\}$ of functions with the property that for all $x$ either
$\sum_{i\le n}h_i(x)=1$ or $\sum_{i\le n}h_i(x)=0$, which would be impossible
in case $G$ were connected say.
This shows a gap in Cartan's proof, or at least some carelessness.
One can fix this: let $A$ be the closure of $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ and
$O=\{x:\sum_{i\le n}h_i(x)=1\}$, the set $O$ is the union of the sets
$\{x:h_i(x)>0\}$, hence open.
There is a continuous function $g:G\to[0,1]$ such that $g(x)=1$ if $x\in A$
and such that the closure of $\{x:g(x)>0\}$ is contained in $O$.
Each function $h_i$ is continuous on $O$ and therefore $g\cdot h_i$ is
continuous on $G$. The set $\{g\cdot h_i:i\le n\}$ is as required by Cartan.
To create $g$ work as above and start with the set $K$ of all continuous
non-negative functions $k$ such that $k(x)=2$ for some $x\in A$ and $k(y)=0$
for $y\notin O$. Take a finite subset $\{k_i:i\le m\}$ of $K$ such that
$A\subseteq\bigcup_{i\le m}\{x:k_i(x)>\frac32\}$, and let $k$ be the
pointwise supremum of the $k_i$.
Then $k(x)>\frac32$ if $x\in A$ and the closure of $\{x:k(x)>\frac12\}$
is a subset of $O$. Let $g$ be $\bigl((k-\frac12)\vee 0\bigr)\land 1$.
Then $\{x:g(x)=1\}=\{x:k(x)\ge\frac32\}$ and $\{x:g(x)>0\}=\{x:k(x)>\frac12\}$,
so $g$ is as required.


This does not, however, remove all vestiges of Choice from the proof.
The proof in Engelking's book mentioned above uses, in the present context,
sequences $\langle V_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ of neighbourhoods of $e$ that satisfy
$V_{n+1}^3\subseteq V_n$ for all $n$.
These are not provided by the definition of topological group
(or in general of uniformity) but they need an appeal to the principle
of Dependent Choices $\mathsf{DC}$, as does the usual proof of Urysohn's Lemma.
So one can appeal to Urysohn's Lemma or one can avoid it by going the route
of uniformities but both ways employ the principle $\mathsf{DC}$.
So Cartan's claim that his proof does not use Choice is not completely
justified.
As to your two questions:

Locally compact Hausdorff spaces are uniformizable and hence have many continuous pseudometrics that help you avoid using Urysohn's Lemma. However if the space is not normal or not paracompact then you do not get partitions of unity subordinate to all possible open covers. Cartan used covers of small (compact) pieces of the group and that gave small local partitions of unity.

Look at the proof in Halmos' Measure theory; it uses Tychonoff's theorem to find a function that can be modified into a Haar measure. Maybe the uniqueness of Haar measure allows you to modify the proof in a Cartan-like way so that you get a net that actually converges.


Addendum (2024-12-22): Theorem 8.2 in Abstract Harmonic Analysis I by Hewitt and Ross shows how to construct a left/right invariant pseudometric given a sequence $\langle U_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ of neighbourhoods of $e$ with $U_{n+1}^2\subseteq U_n$ for all $n$.
